# How to make titles with background?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a title overlay an image.  That's easy, but I want it to be a certain width, and have the text in blocks.  Here's an image of what I want:

[image]

I'd like to do this in CSS if possible, but I'm fine with using Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See a live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/zms26/) here. Try this:

**HTML**:

```
<div>
    <span>Hello world</span><br>
    <span>More text here</span>
</div>
```

​**CSS**:

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url(http://www.hotels.tv/london-hotels/images/destinations/1/w97654_8.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image-width: 100%;

}
div span {
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
}
​
```

**EDIT**

In this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/zms26/1/), the text is aligned to the bottom by using `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: bottom` on the parent

**EDIT 2**

For a transparent background, use rgba(), as in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/zms26/2/)

**EDIT 3**

To align the text right, set `text-align: right` on the parent, as in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/zms26/5/)

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to get it to align to the right of the div?  Whenever I set the position to absolute, it puts the two lines on top of each other.

Comment: Try     display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;

Comment: I take it there isn't a way to align it to the right of the div?

Answer (score 2):

Might need a little tweaking to get it exactly how you want to look but here's a starting point.

```
<style>
    #image_container {
        position: relative;
        background-image: url(path/to/image) no-repeat;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
    #image_container .title {
        position: absolute;
        top: 300px;
        background: #000;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<div id="image_container">
    <div class="title">
        <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.  I want the text to be in multiple lines if necessary and give each line a different sized block depending on how much text is in it.

Answer (score 2):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PvZEs/)*

HTML:

```
<div id="background">
    <span>A Movie in the Park:</span>
    <span>Kung Fu Panda</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#background {
    background: url(http://css-tricks.com/examples/TypeOverImage/images/3754004820_91a5c238a0.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

span {
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:23px;
    font-weight:bold;
    top:150px;
    margin-top:-2px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/FyL6J/

There is no reason why this has to be done using jQuery, but I find `.position()` to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/EcXZZ/

Comment: Sort of, but I want the blocks to be of different sizes depending on text.

Answer (score 1):

The first and simplest way I see to do so would be to get a png image with desired opacity, by example a 1x1 RGB(0,0,0) pixel with 40% opacity for the title background and set your CSS this way :

```
<style>
  .image_holder
  {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
  }
  .image_holder > img
  {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .image_title_overlay
  {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 120px;
    background-image: url('images/black.40%opacity.1x1.png');
    color: 'white';
    padding: 10px 12px;
  }
</style>
<div class="image_holder">
  <img src="image_url.jpg"/>
  <p class="image_title_overlay">A Movie in the Park: <br/>Kung Fu Panda</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use rgba... basically like this:

```
span {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
padding: 5px 17px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TCtR5/3/

Comment: you might want to add a fallback (for older browsers) before your background-color (as you use `rgba`) like a transparent .png image. And after it use: `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);`

Comment: I agree, and I updated my fiddle. I just wanted to show the simplest, progressive way to answer the question.

Comment: AVOID using <h1> and <h2> as your images descriptions, that's what `span`s are for. If you want to improve your SEO than use `h1` only once in your page.